# JAVA: Returning incorrect answer

Tags: java

I have written all the code but am missing something. It's two classes that work together to output specific days of the week. I know I'm doing something stupid wrong, any help would be appreciated

Basically, 2 outputs are correct and 2 are incorrect. The two that are incorrect are previous day and following day, instead of getting the correct answer, I'm getting, say, Monday1 or Tuesday6:

```
import java.util.*;

public class DaysOfTheWeek
{

static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{

  String currentDayOfTheWeek;
  String dayOfTheWeek;

  int dayToFind;

  System.out.println("Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday");
  System.out.print("Enter a day of the week: ");

  currentDayOfTheWeek = console.nextLine();

  Day newDay = new Day(currentDayOfTheWeek);

  newDay.printTheDay();

  dayOfTheWeek = newDay.getThePreviousDay(currentDayOfTheWeek);

  System.out.println();
  System.out.print("The PREVIOUS day from '" + currentDayOfTheWeek + "' ");
  System.out.print("is '" + dayOfTheWeek + "' \n");

  dayOfTheWeek = newDay.getTheNextDay(currentDayOfTheWeek);

  System.out.println();
  System.out.print("The NEXT day from '" + currentDayOfTheWeek + "' ");
  System.out.print("is '" + dayOfTheWeek + "' \n");

  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("How many days in the future from '" + currentDayOfTheWeek +"' \n");
  System.out.print("Do you want (0 - 31)?: ");

  dayToFind = console.nextInt();

  if (validateDay(dayToFind) == true)
  {      
     dayOfTheWeek = newDay.getTheFutureDay(currentDayOfTheWeek, dayToFind);

     System.out.println();
     System.out.print(dayToFind + " days from '" + currentDayOfTheWeek + "' ");
     System.out.print("is '" + dayOfTheWeek + "' \n");                   
  }
  else {
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("Invalid Day '" + dayToFind + "'. Entered day must be between 0 and 31");
  }
}

public static boolean validateDay(int dayToFind)
{
  boolean validDay;

  if ((dayToFind < 0) || (dayToFind > 31))
     validDay = false;
  else
     validDay = true;

  return validDay;
  }
  public class day {
  }
  }
```

Which calls on this class:

```
public class Day
{
private String[] daysArray = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};
private String dayOfTheWeek;

public Day()
{
  dayOfTheWeek = "";
}

public Day(String whichDay)
{
   setTheDay(whichDay);
}

public void setTheDay(String whichDay)
{
   dayOfTheWeek = whichDay;
}
public void printTheDay()
{
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Day of the week entered is: " + dayOfTheWeek);
}

public String getTheFutureDay(String currentDayString, int futureDay)
{     
   int todayArrayPos = -1;

   for (int i = 0; i < daysArray.length; i++)
   {
      if (daysArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase(currentDayString))
      {
         todayArrayPos = i;
         break;
      }
   }

   if (todayArrayPos == -1)
   {
      return "Invalid Day " + futureDay;
   }

   boolean bailOut = false;

   int newFutureDay = 0;
   int j = todayArrayPos;

   while (newFutureDay != futureDay)
   {
    while (j < daysArray.length)
    {
        if (newFutureDay == futureDay)
        {
           bailOut = true;
           break;
        }

        j += 1;
        newFutureDay += 1;
    }

    if (bailOut == true)
    {
        break;
    }

    j = 0;
  }

  return daysArray[j];          
}

public String getTheNextDay(String currentDayString)
{

  String nextDayString = (dayOfTheWeek) + 1;
return nextDayString;
 }

public String getThePreviousDay(String currentDayString)
{


  String previousDayString = (dayOfTheWeek) + 6;
return previousDayString;
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Mark

Comment: You definitely need to provide a more descriptive problem statement. As it stands, we know your code generates days of the week but we don't know specifically what it does or which days it is supposed to generate.

Comment: Basically it loads the days of the week into an array. Requests the user to choose a starting day, then returns Day entered, previous day, next day, then asks to add between 0 and 31 days to return the proper answer. It's currently returning the correct starting day and correct day after adding X days, just not returning previous and next days properly, instead of moving the array to the next element or 6 elements later, it returns day1 or day6. Is that more helpful to understand what I'm asking?

Comment: yes very helpful, see my answer now that you have clarified

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that you add 1 to a string in your next day method.

```
public String getTheNextDay(String currentDayString)
{
  String nextDayString = (dayOfTheWeek) + 1;
  return nextDayString;
}
```

This is going to result in string concatenation - the program doesn't understand that when you ask it to do "Tuesday" + 1 that you want it to say "Wednesday".

You need to do something similar to your get future day method:

```
int todayArrayPos = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < daysArray.length; i++)
{
 if (daysArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase(currentDayString))
 {
  todayArrayPos = i;
  break;
 }
}
int nextDayIndex = i + 1;
//roll over to the first day of the week if the old day was the last day of the week
if (nextDayIndex == daysArray.length) {
 nextDayIndex = 0;
}
return daysArray[nextDayIndex];
```

Try something similar for your previous day as well.